# In Entity Framework, how to get the sql translated by EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

A example:

```
public void Add()
{
    TestDBEntities2 testdb = new TestDBEntities2();
    Test1 test1 = new Test1() { Name="yang"};
    testdb.Tests.Add(test1);
    testdb.SaveChanges();
}
```

how to use ObjectQuery.CommandText to get the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework 6, then you can use [Database.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to intercept database operation. It accepts delegate which takes string parameter (database query text). E.g. output of query to console will look like:

```
testdb.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
testdb.SaveChanges();
```

See [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464)

Comment: @PlantainYao you also can use SQL Server Profiler (it can be found at SQL Server performance tools) to profile queries which SQL Server receives